# RXJS how to delay each observable (http request) and combine all requests output

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I am having issue with setting interval between http requests within one observable.
Thing is - i want to have delay between each http request, wait for all requests to be completed, and perform operation on combined data from all requests.
Of course length of documents array is not known.

Example code:

```
const documents = [
  {
    'documentId': 1,
    'documentName': 'DocName1'
  },
  {
    'documentId': 2,
    'documentName': 'DocName2'
  },
];

function saveDocumentService(document) {
  document['someAnotherData'] = '123';

  return of(document); // in real world http.post()
}

const documentsToSave$ = zip(
  documents,
  interval(200),
  document => {
    document['someDataToBeInserted'] = {'data': 123};
    return saveDocumentService(document);
  }
);

const sub = forkJoin(documentsToSave$).subscribe(documents => {
  console.log('All documents uploaded', documents); // array of responses
});
```

With this approach, only last value is outputted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `merge` with a timer and ignore the output of said timer:

```
import { of, from, timer } from 'rxjs'
import { concatMap, merge, ignoreElements, tap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators'

const documents = [
  {
    'documentId': 1,
    'documentName': 'DocName1'
  },
  {
    'documentId': 2,
    'documentName': 'DocName2'
  },
];

function saveDocumentService(document) {
  document['someAnotherData'] = '123';
  return of(document)
}
from(documents)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(url => saveDocumentService(url).pipe(
      tap(res => console.log('Saved document...')),
      merge(timer(1000).pipe(ignoreElements()))
    )),
    toArray(),
  )
  .subscribe(documents => {
    console.log('Sub:', documents)
  })
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5l2rxs?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `documentsToSave$` of type `Observable<Observable<any>>` replace `forkJoin` with `mergeAll` and `toArray`

```js
const sub = documentsToSave$.pipe(mergeAll(), toArray()).subscribe(documents => {
  console.log('All documents uploaded', documents); // array of responses
});
  }
```

[here is working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqgurz)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rxjs` `pipe` operator to combine `take` and `interval` as

```
counter: number = 0;
items: string[] = ["one", "tow", "three", "four"];

  ngOnInit() {
    interval(2000)
      .pipe(take(this.items.length))
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(console.log(this.items[this.counter++]));
      });
  }
```

**Edit:** You need to create an Observable stream using `Observable.create` where you can use `setInterval` in create observables at regular intervals and at the end, you can mark it as complete.

Once subscribed, we would have separate methods executed once a new value is emitted and once the observable is marked complete

```
obs: Observable<any>;
counter: number = 0;
items: string[] = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];



ngOnInit() {
    this.obs = Observable.create(observer => {
      let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
        observer.next(this.items[this.counter++]);
        if (this.counter >= this.items.length) {
          clearInterval(intervalID);
          observer.complete();
        }
      }, 1000);
    });

    this.obs.subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
      },
      () => {
        console.log("complete");
      }
    );
  }
```

Stackblitz at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-regular-interval-observables-with-complete

Comment: With your approach, subscribe will output each time `items` element will got fired. I want to wait for ALL requests to be completed to handle them in subscribe.

Comment: @Klepstryk please see my updated answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Ok, in your updated code, subscribe will still fire each item dispatched, complete will of course fire once, when complete, but without combined all responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `combineLatest`. But be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value. You can see the documentation for more information: 
[combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)

Comment: Again - with your approach, subscribe will output each time items element will got fired. I want to wait for ALL requests to be completed to handle them in subscribe.